# Why am I getting an error when using a django generic view?

Tags: python, django, django-2.1

i have just started using django, and I keep getting this error now. Also not sure how I can give an additional parameter to the view (url for example).

Will appreciate any help

In urls.py

```
path('page/<path:url>', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='pages/page.html'))

<a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'channels:page' post.url %}" target="_blank">
```

Comment: Can you share the error code? What is your intent and goal for additional parameter?

Comment: Right now with this code I'm getting an error of `Reverse for 'page' not found. 'page' is not a valid view function or pattern name.`

Comment: path('page/<path:url>', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='pages/page.html'), name='page')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just add `name='page'` to your path to make a call in reverse

```
path('page/', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='pages/page.html'), name='page')
```